# Replace a value in a data frame from other dataframe in r

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, outer-join, right-join

Hi I have two dataframes, based on the id match, i wanted to replace table a's values with that of table b.

sample dataset is here :

```
a = tibble(id = c(1, 2,3),
           type = c("a", "x", "y"))
b= tibble(id = c(1,3),
          type =c("d", "n"))
```

Im expecting an output like the following :

```
c= tibble(id = c(1,2,3),
          type = c("d", "x", "n"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `dplyr` v1.0.0, the [`rows_update()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows.html) function was introduced for this purpose:

```r
rows_update(a, b)

# Matching, by = "id"
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#      id type 
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 d    
# 2     2 x    
# 3     3 n
```

Comment: Nice, this is the way (+1)! I didn't know `rows_update()`.

Comment: cool ! Is there a way to run either `left_join()` or `rows_update()` depending on whether dataset `a` already has the columns in `b` ? I'd like one function that just either adds or updates.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `dplyr::left_join` and `dplyr::coalesce`

```r
library(dplyr)
a %>%
    rename(old = type) %>%
    left_join(b, by = "id") %>%
    mutate(type = coalesce(type, old)) %>%
    select(-old)
## A tibble: 3 × 2
#     id type 
#. <dbl> <chr>
#1     1 d    
#2     2 x    
#3     3 n
```

The idea is to join `a` with `b` on column `id`; then replace missing values in `type` from `b` with values from `a` (column `old` is the old `type` column from `a`, avoiding duplicate column names).